# Unreal Engine 4 game using phone sensor value measurement

Tags: unreal-engine4

In the process of preparing for the development of a built-in mobile phone game, we designed a game that affects the player using the data obtained from the user's movement by using the sensor built into the smartphone as a control device. Included in Unreal Engine 4 UE4duino when implementing the game I tried to get the acceleration and velocity values of the cell phone using the functions and blueprints that have been created. But I don't know how.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.